# Modification of Linear Least Square

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

We are given a matrix $A$ and vectors $b,d$ of appropriate size and we want to solve

$$\begin{cases}\min_x ||Ax-b||_2 \\ \text{s.t.}\\ 0\leq x\leq 2d\end{cases}$$ where the inequality has to be understood componentwise.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Does there exist an explicit solution?
Without the constraint $0 \leq x \leq 2d$ this is the linear least-square problem. Of course we could take the inequality in as a penalty contraint, but maybe there already exist more sophisticated possibilities, that I am not aware of?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to solve this kind of problem.
See for example [this](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2016/3934872/) and [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379509002341).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. In the papers you linked algorithms are derived that solve the problem. Do you by any chance know papers that have the focus more on the explicit solution (or finding an approximate solution)? Something similar to $x=A^+b$ where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose-Inverse for linear least squares?

Comment: $||Ax-b||_2 $ is different from $||Ax-b||^2$